# Why is ".git/objects/17" special? Why git source code determines this naming as insane?

Tags: c, git

In this source code,

https://github.com/git/git/commit/07af88913662f1179ba34b92370a6df24263ae5f

```c
    if (sizeof(path) <= snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/17", objdir)) {
        warning(_("insanely long object directory %.*s"), 50, objdir);
        return 0;
    }
    dir = opendir(path);
```

commiter says

```
We probe the "17/" loose object directory for auto-gc, and
use a local buffer to format the path
```

but, why?
I searched a hell, but cannot understand.

Comment: Why not simply comment on that commit and directly ask the folks that did the change? Seems awfully longwinded posting here and hoping someone knowing this detail notices this question.

Comment: @Filburt why shoudn't ask a question here while this site is knowledge sharing service?

Comment: Note that the commit *removes*  this code and replaces it with function call to `git_path`. The return code of `snprintf` is the number of characters that (would) have been written. If it is greater than the buffer size, the resulting string would be too long for the buffer. A buffer which is too small might be bug. Or maybe the length of the resulting path depends on the path where the user has put the working copy.

Comment: Hi @Bodo, thank you but I notice that as well. I just don't know what is the difference of `objects/17` and `objects/aa or objects/bb or whatever`,

Comment: `17` isn't special in this case. They just randomly pick one because files should be evenly spread out over directories and if `17` contains too many files then they trigger a gc. It's an arbitrary choice that was made at one point in the past. Source: see the comment at the beginning of the method (not visible in the diff).

Comment: Thank you @JoachimSauer, yes I read the comment, but you know you sometimes never have an `17` directory, don't you? Or, it means like "There are 1296 possible combinations of letters and numbers, and if first object is 17 it should git gc" ?

Comment: The digits are hex, so there's only 256 different options. The file names are SHA-1 values. The first two digits of the file name are used for the directory. If a directory `17` doesn't exist then that means that no file was to be written that started with those two digits, which in turn strongly suggests (but doesn't necessarily proof) that there are not very many files in total (since files should be roughly evenly spread). In other words: they only care about the order of manitude of files and not the exact nubmer, so checking one directory instead of all is sufficient.

Comment: @JoachimSauer ah sorry, it's 256. And now I got it. I just didn't understand `they should git gc if first directory is 17?` but I understand your explaination. 1: just determine 1 directory randomly => 2: check for size of objects inside it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @eeeeeeeeengo The additional information in your comments shows that the question doesn't really correspond to what you want to know. That's why the question should be [edit]ed and improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git uses SHA-1 or SHA-256 to identify objects, and these hashes are designed to be indistinguishable from random.  Therefore, the number of objects that are stored in one directory is, on average, 1/256th of the total number of objects.  It would be inefficient to traverse all possible objects, so as a result, Git picks just one directory, reads the number of objects, and extrapolates by multiplying by 256.

Any option here is fine, and picking a fixed value simplifies the tests very significantly, since they can then be deterministic.  The Git developers (and users in general) like deterministic behavior because it's easier to reason about, and picking a directory at random could result in different behavior between two no-op commands where one runs a GC and the other doesn't.

As to why directory `17` and not `42` or `ff`?  Because Junio, the author of that patch and the current maintainer, chose `17` and it has some special meaning to him which he hasn't chosen to share.  Even as a Git contributor, I don't know why he chose it (and I'm not aware of any other contributors besides Junio who know, either) and pressuring him about his reasons would be rude and insensitive, so we haven't done that.

Comment: In some circles, the number 17 has a tradition of being used as [a typical random number](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/R/random-numbers.html).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @JoachimSauer I got it.

They just pick one directory to find a size.

It's enough because the objects are spread evenly. If directory doesn't exist, you can skip because it's already small size.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Why git source code determines this naming as insane?" If your real question is something like "Why does Git check the number of files in `.git/objects/17` to control auto-gc?" then this is not related to the change in the commit or the code snippet shown in the question. In this case you should edit the question accordingly. That's why I downvote both question and answer.